# Android Image Gallery Crop Image and set ImageView

Tags: android, image, android-intent, imageview

i am having some issues with setting an ImageView with the object returned from the gallery intent. I must be doing something wrong but when i debug it, everything seems to be in its right place. It doesn't throw any exceptions, It just changes my image to nothing.

I was trying to follow other guides and tutorials on stackoverflow to get my answer but i cant get it working.

this calls the gallery fine, But it doesn't allow croping...

```
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   final ImageView profileImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.profile_user_image);
    profileImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent  data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            Uri picUri = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(picUri,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

                    // Set The Bitmap Data To ImageView
                    BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                    o.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
                    o.inScaled = true;
                    ImageView bitmapview = (ImageView) _this.findViewById(R.id.profile_user_image);

                    bitmapview.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            //bitmapview.setImageResource(R.drawable.female_icon);  // KNOWN FILE
            bitmapview.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath,o)); // Gallery File. 


        }
    }
}
```

I don't know what i am missing, the
the ImageView is restricted to 150dp x 150dp

I have tried changing it to a known resource which works fine, but using this method just fails every time, no matter what i attempt.

Answer (score 0):

crop image in android by using `com.android.camera.action.CROP`. after picking image url from gallery.

```
Intent i = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");  
i.setClassName("com.android.camera", "com.android.camera.CropImage");  
File f = new File(filePath);  
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(f);  
i.setData(uri);  
i.putExtra("crop", "true");  
i.putExtra("aspectX", 1);  
i.putExtra("aspectY", 1);  
i.putExtra("outputX", 96);  
i.putExtra("outputY", 96);  
i.putExtra("noFaceDetection", true);  


intent.putExtra("return-data", true);                                  
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CROP_ICON);
```

When the picture select Activity return will be selected to save the contents.in onActivityResult:

```
Bundle extras = data.getExtras();  
if(extras != null ) {  
    Bitmap photo = extras.getParcelable("data");  
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
    photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, stream);  
        / / The stream to write to a file or directly using the
}
```